# MySQL query to find missing values in time series

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing thousands of customer records, with customer ids ideally repeating for every month.

```
Customer Org | CustomerID | Month
001          | 111        | Jan-15
001          | 112        | Jan-15
001          | 113        | Jan-15
001          | 111        | Feb-15
001          | 112        | Feb-15
001          | 111        | Mar-15
001          | 113        | Mar-15
```

I would like to write a SQL query that gives me 'inconsistent' customers within a customer org, i.e those who do not have records every month.

For eg, if I pass the customer org '001', the expected output needs to be

```
Jan-15 | Feb-15 | Mar-15
112    | 112    | -
113    | -      | 113
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? In my opinion you need use PIVOT.

Comment: MySQL. I have edited the qtn and tag to reflect MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: Look for that. It's look similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: is it possible that multiple entry for a customer can exist in the same month?

Comment: @SubrataDey yes, I have the same customer ids repeating per month for accounting purposes and would like to identify the missing ones.